# Did Matt Drudge sell the Drudge Report?

Tags: politics, media

After President Trump today tweeted "he gave up on Drudge", quite a lot of his responses claimed that Matt Drudge sold the Drudge Report and is under a Non-Disclosure Agreement. Here is a sample tweet. (There are many more - I have seen tons of similar claims. Just search "Drudge" on twitter.)

> Matt Drudge no longer owns nor runs the Drudge Report.
>
> A non-disclosure agreement was signed with the buyers and so no one was notified of the sale.
>
> The political views of the new owners is obvious.
>
> I never read it any more. https://t.co/5lMeQQkkfi
>
> — Nathan Simar (@squashpants) [April 18, 2020](https://twitter.com/squashpants/status/1251654674299736065?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw)

This claim has been circulating on Reddit as well.

News site Sparta Report claims that Drudge has been sold as well: https://www.spartareport.com/2019/12/breaking-drudge-report-appears-to-have-been-sold/

Disrn claims that Rasmussen has claimed this as well: https://disrn.com/news/rasmussen-on-drudge-report-we-dont-think-matt-is-there-anymore-word-is-he-sold-just-waiting-for-confirmation

Is this true? Did Matt Drudge sell the Drudge Report?

Comment: This "correction" may be a partial explanation: https://www.infowars.com/drudge-twitter-indicates-drudgereport-com-no-longer-owned-by-matt-drudge/

Comment: @DavePhD Wow, a legitimate use for an Infowars article on Skeptics.SE! I never thought that day would come.

Answer (score 2):

The ownership of Drudge Report does not appear to be public information. There is no real documentation that I can find one way or other. The widespread speculation about the sale is supported by circumstantial evidence. We will not know unless and until someone with first-hand knowledge discloses and documents ownership.

[Here](https://guides.loc.gov/company-research/private) is a guide from the US Library of Congress to the kinds of sources one can look at when researching privately-owned companies. So far I've found no real reporting of a sale on the open internet or in LexisNexus. There *might* be a meaningful record of ownership at the state level, but I'm not finding any indication of what state this record would be in. As [this article from Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/alexandrawrage/2015/08/18/ownership-of-privately-held-companies-privacy-versus-transparency/#2b9837775fdc) mentions, it was only since 2006 that private companies need to divulge there real owners in the UK, and no such law exists in the United States. The speculation is only that, but there is no concrete evidence that it is wrong either.

Comment: Why should we trust your account? Can you find someone saying "This is not public." It is a weird concept to me that the ownership of a company is not public (even if the company itself is private). Are there not public records?

Comment: I've added a new paragraph with sources.